# Is LINQ to SQL and Dotnetnuke is good choice or we should stick to 3 Tier architecture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, dotnetnuke

Project Scenario

Technology : Dotnetnuke (Approx. 100 - 150 screens)

Data Architecture : LINQ to SQL selected with Codesmith PLINQO

Modules are customized, so its fine if it does not work with Oracle or MySQL as backend

So, the question is

Due to selection of LINQ to SQL in place of 3-tier provider model, it will create any issue ?

is it recommended to use dynamic data website in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used Linq to SQL for a n-tier system and it was magical, a bit of a learning curve but the pain is worth the gain.

However, I recommend you look into [Entity Framework,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx) as Linq to SQL is being deprecated and replaced by EF. We found that out the hard way. Linq to SQL is still going to exist, but no new features will be created for it and will eventually stop being supported.

EF has a lot of the same core principles however, so it is definately worth learning.

Hope this helps,

Kyle